# How to change value of a variable in the spec.ts file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I want to change the value of a variable in the spec. ts file

ts file

```
notChangeVariable :number = 5

exampleFunction(){
let changeVariable = 10
}
```

I am able to change the value of 'notChangeVariable' inside spec.ts file by
`component.notChangeVariable =15`

How can I change the value of 'changeVariable ' the same way inside the spec.ts

Comment: `changeVariable` is a private variable declared inside `exampleFunction` scope, you can't change it outside

Comment: I have a testing error when I need to declare data inside the private variable. Does that mean Its bad code written? Can you have a look at this error I got in an another thread       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486099/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-length-angular-unit-t